# Lax-Milgran theorem with the Poisson equation

Tags: integration, sobolev-spaces, boundary-value-problem, poissons-equation

Let $ \Omega $ be a bounded domain in $\mathbb R^3$ with smooth boundary. Consider the Poisson equation
$$
-\Delta u=f
$$
where $ f\in C_0^{\infty}(\Omega) $ and $f$ is null outside $\Omega$.

I'm not sure I understand the Lax-Milgram theorem. Does it say that we can find the solution in $ H_0^1$ whose support is included inside $\Omega$?

Comment: What is your formulation of Lax Milgram?

Comment: Not very pretentious: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_formulation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the continuous bilinear function:
\begin{equation}
B\colon H_0^1(\Omega)\times H_0^1(\Omega)\rightarrow\mathbb{R},
(u,v)\mapsto B(u,v)=\int_\Omega\nabla u\cdot\nabla v,
\end{equation}
which is coercive due to the Poincaré inequality. There exists a constant $C>0$ only depending on $\Omega$, so that:
\begin{equation}
\forall u\in H_0^1(\Omega)\colon
B(u,u)=\|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2
\geq C\|u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}^2.
\end{equation}
Notice that $H_0^1(\Omega)=W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)\subseteq H^1(\Omega)=W^{1,2}(\Omega)\subseteq L^2(\Omega)$ and since $W_0^{1,p}(\Omega)$ is defined as the closure of $C_\mathrm{c}^\infty(\Omega)$ in $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$, $H_0^1(\Omega)$ is a closed subspace of the Hilbert space $L^2(\Omega)$ and therefore itself a Hilbert space with the restriction of $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_{L^2(\Omega)}$ to $H_0^1(\Omega)$.

The Lax-Milgram theorem (which can be proved using the Riesz representation theorem to which it is similar) can now be applied to $B$. For every $f\in H_0^1(\Omega)$ there exists a $u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$, so that:
\begin{equation}
\forall v\in H_0^1(\Omega)\colon
B(u,v)=\langle f,v\rangle_{L^2(\Omega)}
\Leftrightarrow
\int_\Omega(\Delta u+f)v=0,
\end{equation}
which means that $u$ is a weak solution of $\Delta u=-f$.